# cmake isn't producing a usable executable

Tags: cmake

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.2.1 FATAL_ERROR)
project("soxy")

add_definitions(-std=c99)

include_directories(soxy)

# Includes
include(ExternalProject)

ExternalProject_Add(
    LibUV
    GIT_REPOSITORY "https://github.com/libuv/libuv.git"
    GIT_TAG "v1.4.2"
    CONFIGURE_COMMAND sh <SOURCE_DIR>/autogen.sh && ./configure --prefix=${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/libuv/src/LibUV
    PATCH_COMMAND ""
    BUILD_COMMAND "make"
    BUILD_IN_SOURCE 1
    PREFIX ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/libuv
)

ExternalProject_Get_Property(LibUV install_dir)

add_library(libuv STATIC IMPORTED)
set_property(TARGET libuv PROPERTY IMPORTED_LOCATION ${install_dir}/src/LibUV/lib/libuv.a)
set( SOXY_BIN src/soxy.c )
set(SOXY_SRC
    src/file_utils.c
    src/http_parser.c
    src/http_request.c
    src/path_utils.c
    src/string_utils.c
)

add_executable(soxy src/soxy.c ${SOXY_SRC})
add_dependencies(soxy LibUV)
include_directories(${install_dir}/src/LibUV/include)
target_link_libraries(soxy libuv)
```

This creates a Makefile without error and allows me to run make.

But soxy.c contains the int main function {}, but is isn't being run when i execute ./soxy

Comment: Do you get any errors when you launch the executable?

Comment: ... better yet, what is the full output when you run that command?

Comment: the output is nothing.  ./soxy runs but doesn't do anything.  The first line of the int main is a LOGF (macro for printing), that doesn't execute

Comment: From what you wrote, it is unlikely that CMake is the culprit here. You should double check that it builds what you expect by running `VERBOSE=1 make` on a cleaned build and check the compiler command line in the output. But usually, as soon as the project compiles and links, there's not that much on the CMake side of things that can go wrong.